# jQuery/CSS: count elements with certain classes, but without one specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I have label, which has classes status-label and unavailable.
I want to count all those containing it and exclude those, which have also class named "hide"

```
<label class="status-label unavailable"> should be selected
while
<label class="status-label unavailable hide"> shouldn't
```

I have tried to count the result like this:

```
var invalidConfigs=$("label.status-label.unavailable").not(".hide").length;
```

this didn't work either:

```
var invalidConfigs=$("label.status-label.unavailable:not(.hide)).length;
```

Comment: The first version of your code works fine - http://jsfiddle.net/gn601536/ The second version also works without the missing `"` - http://jsfiddle.net/gn601536/

Comment: $("label.status-label.unavailable").filter(":not('.hide')").length

Comment: than I must have something wrong elsewhere...

Comment: Try using the browser console - http://www.wickedlysmart.com/hfjsconsole/

Comment: @max would love to, but the app I am working on runs in... IFRAME... don't ask.

Comment: Um, there is no problem using the browser console even with iframes like in the stackoverflow editor.

Comment: When are you making the `$().length` call?  Make sure the DOM has loaded by putting it in a `$(function() { ...` if possible - or (as mentioned it's in a iframe) when the iframe as finished loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var invalidConfigs = $("label.status-label.unavailable:not(.hide)")
   .css("color", "red") // just for demo purposes
   .length;
console.log(invalidConfigs);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label class="status-label unavailable"> should be selected</label>
<label class="status-label unavailable hide"> shouldn't</label>
```

You are missing an end quote in your selector.

`.css("color", "red")` is just for the demo to make it visually apparent which element is selected.

Comment: The difference here is that jQuery will use the `:not` pseudo selector if the browser supports it while `.not('.hide')` will filter the result set after the fact. The former being slightly faster if you have a huge amount of elements.

Comment: Can you add an explanation how this is any different from the code that was in the question?

Comment: Well for starters it does not have a syntax error... The error in the OP's code was so small that I don't feel a lengthy explanation is need.

Comment: No "lengthy" explanation, but a simple "you missed a quote" might have been the problem (however unlikely).  Without any explanation, it looks like you just copied the question, fixed the typo then changed how it worked to add a colour instead of returning the count (despite the question asking for the count) - ie it looks like this adds nothing.  Do you see why I asked?

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
var hideClassLabels=$('label.hide');
var notHideLabels=$('label.status-label').not(hideClassLabels);
console.log(notHideLabels.length);
```

Hope this helps